# Issues calculating quartiles in Java

Tags: java, statistics

I'm making a simple statistics calculator that calculates the mean, median, mode, range, quartiles 1 and 3, minimum, maximum, and standard deviation. So far, I haven't had any issues with most of the methods, except quartiles. Quartiles, by their nature, are different according to the amount of data present. For example, with 5 sets of data, the 1st quartile would be the value between the first and second value. However, with 7 sets of data, the 1st quartile would be the second value. How can I change the following method to accommodate for this?

```
public static double q1(double[] m, int num) {
    int q1 = num/4;

    if (m.length%2 == 1) {
        return m[q1];
    }
    else {
        return (m[q1-1] + m[q1]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

The values passed to the method are the array that contains the data, and the number of values in the array (double[]m, int num)

I have the same issue with quartile 3, which is as follows:

```
public static double q3(double[] m, int num) {
    double q = num*.75;
    int q3 = (int) q;

    if (m.length%2 == 1) {
        return m[q3];
    }
    else {
        return (m[q3-1] + m[q3]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

The current method checks for an even or odd amount of data, but more is needed for a correct calculation.

Comment: This does not appear to match the statistical definition of quartile: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile  You need to find the lowest , median, and highest values to calculate the quartiles.

Comment: My method does not match, no. That's currently my main issue.
I have all of those values, but I'm unsure what to do with them.